# How to change value of "DrawingResizeType"

Tags: c#, visio, visio-2010

This code is not working - the page size doesn't change:

```
canvas.Window.Application.ActivePage.PageSheet.get_CellsU("DrawingResizeType").FormulaU = "1";
```

canvas is

```
AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.AxDrawingControl canvas;
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong and how it can be corrected?

Image VSD1 shows the original diagram. After changing the value to 1, it should look like VSD2.

[image: VSD1]
[image: VSD2]

## **Update**

Okay, I used the macro recorder and found this is the VB code

[VB code]

```
ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.AutoSize = True
Application.ActiveWindow.Page.AutoSizeDrawing
```

I tried the same in C#, but it throws COM exception

[C# code]

```
canvas.Window.Application.ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = (int)Visio.VisDiagramServices.visServiceVersion140;
Visio.Page p = (Visio.Page)canvas.Window.Application.ActiveWindow.Page;
p.AutoSize = true;
p.AutoSizeDrawing(); //throws COM exception 0x86DB0C89
```

Exception details
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x86DB0C89):

An exception occurred.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.IVPage.AutoSizeDrawing()
   at VisioDemo.Form1.btnReConnect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs ea) in C:\Form1.cs:line 121
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5472 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

VisioDemo
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0

### CodeBase: file:///C:/bin/x86/Debug/VisioDemo.exe

Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx
    Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.0.4756.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft acknowledged this issue as genuine Visio problem and released a patch

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878227